# Скопировать один байт в определенный индекс массива char

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Нужно при помощи memcpy скопировать байт 0x00 в определенный индекс массива char'ов структуры WSABUF (Winsock) lpBuffers->buf Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int WSAAPI WSARecv(SOCKET s, LPWSABUF lpBuffers, DWORD dwBufferCount, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRecvd, LPDWORD lpFlags, LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine);

typedef struct _WSABUF {
    ULONG len;     /* the length of the buffer */
    CHAR FAR *buf; /* the pointer to the buffer */
} WSABUF, FAR * LPWSABUF;
```

В lpBuffers->buf указатель на массив char'ов где нужно по нужному индексу изменить один байт при помощи memcpy

Comment: `buf[index] = 0`?

Comment: Я уже так пробовал и как я понял, так я перезаписываю именно указатель на массив. А надо изменить сам массив на который указывает этот указатель. memcpy работает вроде-бы (байты пакета меняются и меня кикает с сервера), но я не понимаю как им пользоваться.

Comment: Покажите относящийся к делу **код**

Comment: Добавил пояснения

Comment: Проще всего `lpBuffers->buf[i] = 0;`. Но если очень хочется, то можно и извратиться `memcpy(lpBuffers->buf + i, "", 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эмм... У вас `lpBuffers` - указатель на массив структур `WSABUF`, в каждой из которых есть поле-указатель на массив `char`'ов. Соответственно, следующая строка присвоит 0 `i`-му элементу массива `buf` в `0`-й структуре `WSABUF` массива `lpBuffers`:

```
lpBuffers->buf[i] = 0;
```

Это эквивалентно следующей строке:

```
lpBuffers[0].buf[i] = 0;
```

Для обнуления `i`-го элемента массива `buf` `j`-й структуры `WSABUF` массива `lpBuffers`, надо записать:

```
lpBuffers[j].buf[i] = 0;
```

Разумеется, мы полагаем, что все указатели `buf` проинициализированы, и что  `j<dwBufferCount` и `i<len`.

Не знаю, что вы конкретно желаете получить, мой ответ соответствует полноте вашего вопроса и, надеюсь, окажется для вас полезным.